# What is the difference between this code and just addChild()

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uikit

This is the code I found in one of apples Swift tutorials: (in a `UIViewController` class)

```
private func attachChild(_ viewController: UIViewController) {
    addChild(viewController)

    if let subview = viewController.view {
        subview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(subview)

        subview.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        subview.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor).isActive = true
        subview.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        subview.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    viewController.didMove(toParent: self)
}
```

I am wondering what the difference is between calling attachChild and just to addChild or in other words what does this function exactly do?

Comment: It basically is `addChild`, but adds some constraints to the child VC's view.

Comment: and what is didMove for and adding the vc's view as subview

Comment: Adding the VC's view as subview is as straightforward as it sounds. `didMove` simply tells the VC that it is being added to a container, a bit like a delegate method. [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621405-didmove)